# How to add own custom CSS in prestashop 1.6?

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I want to my html template in Prestashop 1.6 framwork

prestashop in which location place css for custome design

Comment: _But it doesn't working_ means?

Comment: i dont know how to place css in prestashop

Comment: Just go to edit section and from at the top menu select {} and put your css there

Answer (score 2):

Your template folder is located in root/themes/default-bootstrap/

There you have your .tpl like header.tpl, footer.tpl and many others.

If you want to edit a module .tpl file you go to root/themes/default-bootstrap/modules and search for the module you want

Example: Cart located in header you can edit the html by going to root/themes/default-bootstrap/blockcart/blockcart.tpl

If you want to add custom CSS to your template you can add css to your global template file located in: root/themes/default-bootstrap/css/global.css

Comment: I wouldn't edit that file. If you don't have a specific inheritance requirement (like overriding a specific module css) you can place a custom.css file in the /themes/default-bootstrap/css/autoload/ folder. Giving it a name like z-custom.css will ensure it is the last file loaded. I'm working on how to establish a specific load sequence outside of the autoload folder to address the inheritance issues so I don't have an answer to that yet.